# how to interpret this regular expression

Tags: regex

I am having a lot of trouble interpreting this expression and I am getting really lost trying to read it. can someone help me?

> ^[^?]*(?:htaccess|access_log)(?:[.][^/?]*)?(?:[~])?(?:[?].*)?$

I know that ^ means to start at the beginning of the line, [^?] not matching a "?" i think, and then (?:) not sure what this does or how to interpret the rest of the line. Im thinking that htaccess|access_log means its an or statement so either htacces or access_log.  [.][^/?] is a . followed by not a "?" but then what would the earlier [^?] mean...

What would an example of something this matches?

Comment: try http://www.myezapp.com/apps/dev/regexp/show.ws

Comment: [^/?]   [] means a set of characters, a ^ means not when its inside the [].  meaning  not /?

Comment: what does [^?] mean then?

Comment: `(?:)` is a non-capture group. It needs to match either htaccess or access_log but it wont capture them.

Comment: errr  it means not ?

Comment: ohh i thought /? or ? would mean something else but it literally means not "/?" and not "?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are plenty of [explainers](http://liveforfaith.com/re/explain.pl) that will breakdown a regular expression for you.

To be concise, the caret inside of a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[^ ]` is the negation operator, meaning match anything **NOT** in the character class. The `?:` placed inside of an opening parentheses is a [non-capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) which specifies that the group is not to be captured, but to group expressions, and `|` is the [alternation operator](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

I would recommend taking a look at these sites for basic use of regular expressions.

- [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)
- [Rexegg (Regex Tutorial)](http://www.rexegg.com/)

Regular Expression:

```
^                # the beginning of the string
[^?]             # any character except: '?'
(?:              # group, but do not capture:
  htaccess       #   'htaccess'
 |               #   OR
  access_log     #   'access_log'
)                # end of grouping
(?:              # group, but do not capture (optional):
  [.]            #   any character of: '.'
  [^/?]          #   any character except: '/', '?'
)?               # end of grouping
(?:              # group, but do not capture (optional):
  [~]            #   any character of: '~'
)?               # end of grouping
(?:              # group, but do not capture (optional):
  [?]            #   any character of: '?'
  .*             #   any character except \n (0 or more times)
)?               # end of grouping
$                # before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```